# tiny_malloc_from_free_list Error

Tags: ios, adwhirl

I am using my app on iPad then it got error tiny_malloc_from_free_list and it causes the application  to crash. Where as I know it is causes by adWhirl Which i have used in my app and the method is

> (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error

```
{
    banner.delegate=self;

    [adWhirlView adapter:self didFailAd:error];

}
```

I don't know what is the cause of problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add the full error message and provide a backtrace (the bt command in the debugger).

Comment: Ok i will show you soon

Comment: It was coming only in ipad while setting delegate of ADBannerview .I just commented out the delgate setting line and every thing now working fine.Thanks for your response.